# How to show a Qt widget on a Gstreamer(waylandsink) rendering widget in Weston?

Tags: c++, qt, gstreamer, wayland

I want to show a Qt button widget on the Gstreamer rendering widget,
This is my source code for gstreamer waylandsink render on the QWidget,

```
QPlatformNativeInterface *native =
            QGuiApplication::platformNativeInterface();
struct wl_surface *surface = static_cast<struct wl_surface *>(
native->nativeResourceForWindow("surface", m_topWidget->windowHandle()));
gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle(
            GST_VIDEO_OVERLAY (GST_MESSAGE_SRC (msg)),
            (guintptr) surface
        );
gst_video_overlay_set_render_rectangle(
            GST_VIDEO_OVERLAY (GST_MESSAGE_SRC (msg)),
            rect.x(), rect.y(),
            rect.width(), rect.height()
        );
```

So, How can I show the button on the rendering widget?

Comment: I find a workaround, add the button on other QWidget, and let the widget show after the rendering widget.